# How do I append data to a binary file with an hex editor?

Tags: binary

I'm trying to append data to a binary file in ubuntu using the hexedit software. Is it an impossibility to append data to a binary file without overwriting the data already present in the file in ubuntu?

Comment: I haven't used dd before. Are you familiar with hexedit? Do you know how to write the less down or greater than character "<" and ">" without the cursor moing to the first line in the file?

Comment: It's hard to understand the issue you're having here - in `hexedit`, the `<` and `>` characters are used to toggle between the start and end of the file - what are you expecting them to do? To append data, press `>` then type the new byte values, then hit F2 to save

Comment: Sorry if you don't understand me. I need to write down the < character instead of toggling between the start and end of a file. Do you understand?

Comment: Ah yes I see - in that case, you will need to use the *hexadecimal values of* the characters, as explained in [Frobozz's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1276363/178692)

Answer (score 3):

hexedit does apparently overwrite the entire file if you save any change; even if you were merely appending data.

Entering symbols (such as "<" ">") can be problematic as they represent hexedit commands.  To enter them as file content, use "tab" key to switch to hex editing and enter their hexadecimal representations ( 3c and 3e accordingly).  And as these are hardly the only keys like this, I'd advise you have an ASCII table handy anytime you are in a hex editor.

Many Linux admins will use the venerable "dd" when faced with bit-fiddling in binary files.  The following is an example of how to replace a 4 byte section of an 80 byte file of random numbers with zeros at a position 15 bytes into the file:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=file.dat bs=1 count=80 #create primary file
dd if=/dev/zero of=block.dat bs=1 count=4 #create replacement data
dd if=./block.dat of=./file.dat bs=1 count=4 seek=15 conv=notrunc #replace data
```

To "insert" data into a binary file using **dd** is not strictly practical as it involves relocating the second half of the binary file; an evolution that overwrites itself.

However, you can construct a third file that is a concatenation of the first half of your data file, the inserted data, and then the second half of your data file and produce the net effect:

```
# Define where the insertion will take place; the 25th byte
insertPoint=25
# Create new file with the first 24 bytes of data file
dd if=file.dat bs=1 count=$(expr $insertPoint - 1) > file2.dat
# Append insert data
cat insert.dat >> file2.dat
# Append rest of data file
dd if=file.dat bs=1 skip=$(expr $insertPoint - 1) >> file2.dat
```

It should be pointed out that binary files are often such because they are used by services or applications.  As such, care must be taken to ensure  you are not altering a file that is actively being used by some other process.

Comment: I don't want to replace the 4 byte section but will like to insert it into any position in the file without overwriting another four byte section. Let me know if you understand what I'm saying.

Comment: Yes, I have those. Please show me how the insert will be done.

Comment: The second solution worked for appending data at a specific position instead of overwriting. But I had to remove the `- 1`. However I was not able to make a Windows executable work after replacing a string with another string that has a bigger or smaller length.

Comment: Windows executables are frequently "self-checksumming" to prevent hacking.